# Java: How do I mock a method of a field when that field isn't exposed?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm using Java 6, JUnit 4.8.1, and writing a console application.  My application has a member field that isn't exposed …

```
public class MyApp { 
    ...
    private OpportunitiesService m_oppsSvc;

    private void initServices() { 
        …
        m_oppsSvc = new OpportunitiesServiceImpl(…);
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to mock a behavior such that whenever one method from my service is called, (e.g. `m_oppsSvc.getResults()`), the same result is always returned.  How do I do that?  There's no setter method for the field.  I'm currently working with Mockito 1.8.4.  Is it possible to do this with Mockito or some other mock framework?

Comment: Can you not create a setter method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you unit test private methods](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/100959/how-do-you-unit-test-private-methods)?

Comment: What are you trying to test? is `getResults()` public? Does it have a private field associated with it, or is it computed at run time?  Depending on the answers, you may be able to use a 'spy' or mocking might not have anything to do with it and you could use something like `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils` to simply set the private field to the value you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyAppTest { 

    @Mock private OpportunitiesService mocked_m_oppsSvc;
    @InjectMocks MyApp myApp;

    @Test public void when_MyApp_uses_OpportunititesService_then_verify_something() { 
        // given
        given( mocked_m_oppsSvc.whatever()).willReturn(...);

        // when
        myApp.isUsingTheOpportunitiesService(...);

        // then
        verify...
        assertThat...
    }
}
```

Using: [Mockito 1.9.0](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/), [BDD style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavior-driven_development), <strike>[FEST-Assert](https://code.google.com/p/fest/)</strike> [AssertJ](https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @InjectMocks only supports setter injection.

Comment: @InjectMocks can also inject private fields.

Comment: Javadoc was incorrect, it always supported private fields injection. Then setter injection, then constructor injection in 1.9.0. Check InjectmMocks's Javadoc in version 1.9.0 http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

Comment: Correct answer. But I think the problem with code that it breaks "testable code" rules - creation objects and not getting them from construction.

Comment: @EugenMartynov Yeah agreed, this is arguable ; however with today's injection technics (`@Inject` (JSR-330), `@Autowired` (Spring), `@Context` (CXF), etc.), you may not have externally visible dependencies like in the constructor or with setters.

Comment: @Brice I agree also :) I'm from old java world where we don't have annotations.

Comment: Wait, this code will not work! Mockito will assign the private field `m_oppsSvc` in the `MyApp myApp` instance with a mock object, but then the `initServices()` method in `MyApp` will re-assign it with a non-mock instance. So, when the internal `m_oppsSvc` field gets used it will *not* produce mocked behavior as recorded in the test. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Rogerio Well spotted, though the original question doesn't say how `initServices` is used. I assumed it was called by the constructor.

Answer (score 10):

Given that you're already using mockito, why not just use reflection:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyApp { 

    @Mock
    private OpportunitiesService m_oppsSvc;

    private MyApp myApp;


    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
       myApp = new MyApp();
       Field f = MyApp.class.getDeclaredField("m_oppsSvc");
       f.setAccessible(true);
       f.set(myApp, m_oppsSvc);
    }
}
```

It's a bit ugly, but it will do the trick.  Note that this may not be the most efficient way to do it with Mockito, but it will work.

There's also Powermock which should allow you to do this as well using the Whitebox class.  I won't get into the whole details of Powermock but here's the call to inject the private field value, which should be a mock object:

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(myApp, "m_oppsSvc", m_oppsSvc);
```

Comment: does not work in OS 11+. If the field is hidden you'll get a java.lang.NoSuchFieldException when you execute the getDeclaredField method

Answer (score 6):

You should consider attempts to mock a private field a [smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). That is, a sign that either what you're trying to do is either incorrect or that your code is currently structured incorrectly. You should only need to mock public methods or injected dependencies

In the code you've given you should consider injecting OpportunitiesService as follows:

```
public class MyApp { 
    ...
    private OpportunitiesService m_oppsSvc;

    public MyApp(OpportunitiesService oppsSvc) {
        this.m_oppsSvc = oppsSvc;
    }
    ...
}
```

In your test you can then inject a mock as follows:

```
OpportunitiesService mockOpportunitiesService =
    Mockito.mock(OpportunitiesService.class);
Mockit.when(mockOpportunitiesService.someMethod()).thenReturn(someValue);
MyApp app = new MyApp(mockOpportunitiesService);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with JMockit:

```
public class MyAppTest
{
    @Tested MyApp myApp;

    @Test
    public testSomething(final @Capturing OpportunitiesService mockService)
    {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            mockService.getResults(); result = asList("a", "b", "C");
            // record other expectations, if needed
        }};

        myApp.whateverMethodIWantToTest();

        new Verifications() {{
            mockService.doSomething(anyInt);
            // verify other expectations, if needed
        }};
    }
}
```

Even though the implementation class `OpportunitiesServiceImpl` isn't mentioned in test code, its instances (any number of them) will still get properly mocked.

Answer (score -1):

Generally you should use dependency injection and pass the mock object (of type OppportunitiesServiceImpl) in via the constructor, a separate setter or directly to the method (getResults).  You might need to extract an interface for OpportunitiesServiceImpl first.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, this is solved through the use of dependency injection.  In regular (production) mode, your dependency injection container (e.g. Spring or Guice) will inject an instance of `OpportunitiesService` into `MyApp` through your constructor or through a setter.

Then, when you're testing you can "inject" a mock instance manually using the same setter or constructor argument.

Instead of doing

```
m_oppsSvc = new OpportunitiesServiceImpl(…);
```

Try Passing `OpportunitesService` in through `MyApp`'s constructor